# Generating similar lines

Tags: python-requests

I want to generate similar lines in python,
It should have number range only number should change.
I mean I want to generate the same line but the number should go on from 2 to 1000.
EXAMPLE:

```
Jhon has 2 Apples
Jhon has 3 Apples
Jhon has 4 Apples
Jhon has 5 Apples
Jhon has 6 Apples
Jhon has 7 apples
```

I need a python script to generate like this.

Answer (score 0):

```
for num in range(2,1001):
    print(f"Jhon has {num} Apples")
```

This code for solution for your problem. In here I using for loop for generate ittaritvely printing line and formating string concept use for change number variable.